# php...target='_blank'

Tags: php, zen-cart

I want to open a new window after clicking a button and I'm trying to modify the code within Zencart. I think I'm trying to manipulate it in the right place... but I don't know how to go about it:

(For anyone that does know Zencart this was in the paypalwpp.php file, lines 1616-1618)

```
// This is where we actually redirect the customer's browser to PayPal. Upon return from PayPal, they go to ec_step2
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Object Moved");
    zen_redirect($paypal_url . "?cmd=_express-checkout&token=" . $_SESSION['paypal_ec_token'] . $userActionKey);
```

Here was my amateur attempt:

```
zen_redirect( "target='_blank'" . $paypal_url . "?cmd=_express-checkout&token=" . $_SESSION['paypal_ec_token'] . $userActionKey);
```

Of course, I added the "target='_blank'" and it isn't working... how could I go about opening a new window by modifying the above code? Thank You!

Comment: HTTP redirects issued by server responses / PHP scripts don't allow to direct to a particular frame or new window. This must be accomplished in HTML, or with Javascript. The redirect can only be a followup event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely zen_redirect works like a normal redirect.  What I mean is that you would not be able to specify the "target" parameter when doing a redirect.

The "target" parameter is a browser based attribute.

Redirects are server side, for the most part.

I think you are looking for something else, but I am not familiar with zen cart.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this on the page that contains the button, not the page that the button submits to.